# Index not picked with nested field hierarchy but gets picked in the flatten mode

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

so i am struggling for 2 weeks on why does not my indexes get picked when i “explain” my queries.

i have this query:

```
{ “$and”: [

{   "extraProperties.class": "Residential" }, {   "extraProperties.type": "Sale" }, {   "extraProperties.propertyType": "Condo Apartment" }, {   "extraProperties.propertyTypeStyle": "Apartment" } ] }
```

the above query wont pick this index :

```
{ “extraProperties.class”:1 , “extraProperties.type” : 1, “extraProperties.propertyType”:1,“extraProperties.propertyTypeStyle”:1}
```

i have been testing everything these days and finally i decided to flatten the hierarchy and now my query looks like this:

```
{ “$and”: [

{ “class”: “Residential” }, { “type”: “Sale” }, { “propertyType”: “Condo Apartment” }, { “propertyTypeStyle”: “Apartment” }

] }
```

now the above query will pick this index :

```
{ “class”:1 , “type” : 1, “propertyType”:1,“propertyTypeStyle”:1}
```

could someone explain what the hell is going on there?!?!

explain result:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bs_mqO-1FEBHQ_FsBWgP2TQ2jeiQz4q_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, could you add the explain output?

Comment: It works here https://mongoplayground.net/p/_5QNYCReN7n  Please add enough details to reproduce

Comment: hi, i added the explain result to google drive cause it was 80000 characters.i have created all combinations of the indexes that i could just to make it work.but it didn't

@AlexBlex

Comment: @HanielBaez please comment

Comment: The explain suggests you have a arrays in your documents. Is it correct? Please add example documents sufficient to reproduce your results.

Comment: @MasoudyBaBa let's move the conversation here. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229598/index-problem